# root mail - postfix, etc

Tags: root, postfix, mail

for reasons that I cannot seem to divine, my postfix keeps trying to deliver messages to root to root@[MyISP].com, which of course is getting rejected as invalid username by the SMTP gateway at [MyISP].com.  I cannot seem to figure out where its getting this root@MyISP.com address from.  I have a .forward file in /root/, and other stuff that uses mail command seems to get delivered properly.  Where is this coming from?

Ubuntu 18.04    Any suggestions of how to fix would be appreciated.

Comment: You may have an email address in your  (or `root`'s) `crontab` that  you forgot about.

Comment: What is your `myorigin` parameter in Postfix configuration? Postfix adds this by default after `@` when sender or/and recipient address consists of user name only (and by default cron tries to send mail just to `root`).